# Can a monohedral tiling have more than $21$ corner-adjacencies at every tile?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, tiling, tessellations

Suppose we tile the plane with a simply-connected tile $T$, and we wish to ensure that every tile touches at least $k$ other tiles.

If we restrict "touching" to require sharing a positive-measure section of their border, then Euler's formula for planar graphs proves that we can only get $k=6$, a value which is attained by taking $T$ to be the regular hexagon.

However, if we permit adjacency by sharing a corner, we can do better. For instance, the standard tessellation of the plane by squares has $k=8$, and the standard tessellation by equilateral triangles has $k=12$. In fact, one can find a tiling with $k=21$, shown below:

[image]

All of the above examples are *isohedral*, which means that any two tiles can be mapped to each other via an isometry of the plane preserving the tiling. We can consult [*The eighty-one types of isohedral tilings in the plane*](https://mth487.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/the-eighty-one-types-of-isohedral-tilings-in-the-plane.pdf) by Grünbaum and Shephard to confirm that no other isohedral tilings improve on this value.

**Is $\textbf{k=21}$ maximal among monohedral tilings?** (A *monohedral* tiling is one in which we merely require all tiles to be congruent.)

Note that it is possible to find monohedral tilings in which *some* tiles have arbitrarily high corner-adjacency (or edge-adjacency, for that matter), but all such tilings I have found contain other tiles which are not so well-connected.

I'm interested in any improvements to the above $k=21$ solution, and any upper bounds that can be put on $k$ in the monohedral case.

Comment: Just a small suggestion: check the book _Tilings and Patterns_ if you haven't yet; I suspect it goes into more detail than the paper you link, though I've not dug into it in a while. I'll try and take a look in the meantime to see if there's anything specific mentioned there. It might also be worth checking _The Symmetries Of Things_, but I'm pretty sure that book has little coverage of monohedral tilings since the primary interest there is in the symmetries specifically.